# Matlab: Covariances for 1 pixel horizontal and vertical displacement of image

Tags: image, matlab, covariance, grayscale

I have a gray scale image stored in a matrix `Mat` and am asked to extract the covariances for 1 pixel horizontal and vertical displacement.

I thought of using `circshift` and `cov` to extract the covariance.

```
Mat = magic(5); % this represents my gray scale image
MatHs = circshift(Mat,[0 1]); % horizontal displacement
MatVs = circshift(Mat,[1 0]); % vertical displacement

covMatH = cov(Mat,MatHs)
covMatV = cov(Mat,MatVs)
```

However, the result of covMatH and covMatV must be of size 1 by 1 where mine is 2 by 2.
Did I misapplied the `cov` functions or have I not understood the question correctly and this task must be solved completely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your image is 2-dimensional, you will be receiving a `covariance matrix` ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix)) of size `2*2`. You have definitely solved the task of finding the covariance, but each element of the `2*2` matrix represents a different index. Lets say the matrix is `[A B; C D]`. `A` and `D` would represent variance of the inputs. `B` and `C` would represent cross-covariance between the inputs.

Comment: Thank you, so by taking the B or C element using covMatH(1,2) for example, the answer is correct!